# @inaccessable directive not working apollo federation

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway

i have been using this sample project :https://github.com/apollographql/federation-demo
to test @inaccessible and requires directives. @requires directive is working as expected but even after using @inaccessable directive i'm still see the field in schema and is able to request it.

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @inaccessible on FIELD_DEFINITION | INTERFACE | OBJECT | UNION | ARGUMENT_DEFINITION | SCALAR | ENUM | ENUM_VALUE | INPUT_OBJECT | INPUT_FIELD_DEFINITION

  extend type Query {
    topProducts(first: Int = 5): [Product]
    getProduct(id: String, available: Boolean): Product
  }

  type Product @key(fields: "upc") {
    upc: String!
    name: String
    price: Int
    weight: Int
    available: Boolean @inaccessible
  }
`;
```